# How to move all subdirectories to current directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, scripts

I'm new to shell script programming. Suppose we have a file hierarchy like this:

```
/A/B/C/D
/A/B/E/F/G
/A/H/I
/A/H/J/K
```

Note that here we not only have `/A/B/..`, but also `/A/H/...`. All letters are directories. We'd like to transform the hierarchy into:

```
/A/B/C
/A/B/D
/A/B/E
/A/B/F
/A/B/G
/A/H/I
/A/H/J
/A/H/K
```

That is, to move all directories at a depth greater than two (dir A has depth zero), to depth two.
I can use JAVA and C to implement it, but they are a bit too slow. Does anyone know how to use a shell script to implement it?

The pseudo-code is as follow:

```
for each directory D in current directory A // A may have more than one subdirectories
    for each directory d in D
        for each object in d
            if object is a directory
                move object and all descendant subdirectories of object to /A/D;
            end if
        end for
    end for
end for
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for dir in /A/*; do
    find "$dir" -mindepth 2 -depth -type d -exec mv -t "$dir" -- {} +
done
```

This instructs `find` to search for all directories (`-type d`) at least 2 levels underneath (`-mindepth 2`) `$dir` depth-first (`-depth`). For each object it finds it runs `mv -t "$dir" -- <SRC>`. As always, `mv` doesn't allow you to merge a source directory into an existing target directory (but there are ways around that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, A may originally have many subdirectories, then this will be "find /A/B1 ...", "find /A/B2 ...", etc. Is there any way to consider all subdirectories under A?

Comment: I'll address this in an edit to my answer. Please update your question to clarify it according to your comment.

Comment: Hi I met this problem: mv: cannot move `./A/B/C/D/E' to `./A/B/E': Directory not empty      is there anything wrong?

Comment: This happens, because `./A/B/E`, the destination, is a non-empty directory. As I explained in my answer, `mv` doesn't merge directories. Do you want to merge the content of directories of the same name?